# How do I remove the [object HTMLCollection] line at the end of my web page?

Tags: javascript

My code is displaying the expected result, except that at the end, a line displays saying, "[object HTMLCollection]". How do I remove this extra snippet?

I searched for an answer but although there are questions like: "How to remove an item from HTMLCollection?", none is about why these words ([object HTMLCollection]) display and how to remove them. Here's my code:

```
<html>
<body>

<p>This bed is too small.</p>
<p id="p2">This bed is too big.</p>
<p>This bed is just right.</p>

<script>
var par = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var p2 = document.getElementById("p2");
change = () => par[1].innerHTML = "This SUV is too big.";
p2.onclick = change;
document.write(par + "<br />");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to remove the last line from the result:

This bed is too small.

This SUV is too big.

This bed is just right.

[object HTMLCollection]

Comment: Remove the line `document.write(par + "<br />");`

Comment: par is not a string. Par is a collection of elements. Thus, when you document.write(par) the toString() on par gets called, resulting in "[object HTMLCOllection]"

Comment: The short answer is that using a collection of HTML elements as a string -- concatenating it with a string, for instance, which is what you're doing with `par + "<br />"`, or even passing it as-is with `document.write(par)` -- does not produce the result you would expect. The `toString` method on the collection, which is called automatically to get you the string variant of the object, does not amount to representation of contents of its elements, it amounts to `"[object HTMLCollection]"`, which is why you get that at the end of your document.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Yes, you are right Roland Starke, removing the line solved the problem. I guess all HTML elements are objects then?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the line "document.write(par + "
");" solved the problem. It appears that javascript considers HTML elements as objects and not as strings.

I wasn't necessary to write the line in the first place as the text in

tags already displays as strings. I didn't notice this at first.